# Replace values in an array after calculating unix time

Tags: javascript

Hi I need to figure out how to calculate each timestamp for each product and replace them with the uncompressed unix time. My formula for calculating the uncompressed Unix time is:

```
var uncompressedUnixTime = (timeStamp + 21564000);
var compressedUnixTime = new Date((uncompressedUnixTime * 60) * 1000);
```

where the timestamp is the large number and the small number is the ranking so I need to skip the ranking somehow.

This is the sample json below:

```
var products = [
    {
        name: "product1",
        timestamp: [2149440,10,2149800,11,2150160,12,2150520,13,2150880,12],
    },
    {
        name: "product2",
        timestamp: [2149440,10,2149800,11,2150160,12,2150520,13,2150880,12],
    },
    {
        name: "product3",
        timestamp: [2149440,10,2149800,11,2150160,12,2150520,13,2150880,12],,
    }
];
```

Comment: Hey Juan. What exactly is your question? Have you made an effort towards solving this issue yourself, and/or have some code you can share? We'd like to help out but right now I don't see how we can, short of writing the code for you.

Comment: I'm having some difficulties understanding how the timestamp array of each item is actually composed and what you want to return from it.

Comment: It looks like you want to skip even values.

Comment: @Juan You need to define a desired result you want and format. That way we can see your work, your inputs, and your desired output, then we can build a result which meets your criterion.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Furthermore, he needs to make an attempt and form a *specific* question. Even with the correct input and output, StackOverflow is not a code-writing service :)

Comment: I'm so sorry if my question is unclear I am quite a beginner in terms of fetching data from json. basically I need to add a fixed value for each timestamp in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be something like this. But yes, you need to specify what the expected output should like.

```js
const dateFromTimestamp = timestamp => {
  const uncompressedUnixTime = (timestamp + 21564000);
  return new Date((uncompressedUnixTime * 60) * 1000);
}

const isRanking = value => value < 1000; // or whatever test actually works for your case

const processTimestamp = timestamp => isRanking(timestamp) ? timestamp : dateFromTimestamp(timestamp);

const processProduct = ({ name, timestamp }) => ({
  name,
  timestamp: timestamp.map(processTimestamp)
});

const products = [{
    name: "product1",
    timestamp: [2149440, 10, 2149800, 11, 2150160, 12, 2150520, 13, 2150880, 12]
  },
  {
    name: "product2",
    timestamp: [2149440, 10, 2149800, 11, 2150160, 12, 2150520, 13, 2150880, 12]
  },
  {
    name: "product3",
    timestamp: [2149440, 10, 2149800, 11, 2150160, 12, 2150520, 13, 2150880, 12],

  }
];

console.log(products.map(processProduct));
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much! this may not be the answer I am looking for but I found the solution based on this structure.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution:

```
const comUTime = timeStamp => {
      const uncompressedUnixTime = (timeStamp + 21564000);
      const compressedUnixTime = new Date((uncompressedUnixTime * 60) * 100)
      return compressedUnixTime
    }
    var products = [{
        name: "product1",
        timestamp: [2149440, 10, 2149800, 11, 2150160, 12, 2150520, 13, 2150880, 12],
      },
      {
        name: "product2",
        timestamp: [2149440, 10, 2149800, 11, 2150160, 12, 2150520, 13, 2150880, 12],
      },
      {
        name: "product3",
        timestamp: [2149440, 10, 2149800, 11, 2150160, 12, 2150520, 13, 2150880, 12],
      }
    ];
    products.map(({
      name,
      timestamp
    }) => {
      timestamp = timestamp.reduce((m, v, i) => {
        // Logic here
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          m.push(comUTime(v))
        }else {
          m.push(v)
        }
        return m;
      }, [])
      return {
        name,
        timestamp
      }
    })
```

Comment: Hey xdeepakv. If you know it shouldn't be an answer, please don't post it as one. Answers are *never* an alternative to comments. If you want to include code in a comment, consider something like JSFiddle, Plunkr, etc.

Comment: If this is intended to be a full answer to the question, then it is fine here.